# How to get entities from a text and match them to the id of the source file?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy-3

I have a csv file with some columns including an id column and a text column.

Example source file:
[source_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXO0f.png)

I like to extract the entity text and label by using spaCy. Then write the entity text and label to a dataframe with the corresponding source id. It is very well possible that a sentence contains more then one entity. Those entities should have the same id.

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbKeo.png)

I thought that using the pd apply function is the best option to do this, but I get an error. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/test_data.csv')
nlp = spacy.load("nl_core_news_lg")
ner_entities = []

def get_entities(row):
    entity_id = row['id']
    text = row['text']
    doc = nlp(Text)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        ner_entities.append([entity_id, ent.text, ent.label_])

df.apply(lambda row: get_entities(row))
ner_df = pd.DataFrame(ner_entities, columns=['id', 'ent', 'label'])
merged_df = pd.merge(df, ner_df, on='id', how='outer')enter code here
```

I get following error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL9GK.png)

Comment: I think you need to set `axis=1` when applying something to rows. So `df.apply(lambda row: get_entities(row), axis=1)`. Also, but you haven't reached that problem yet, `df.apply` does not alter the dataframe, but only returns a series. You need to save that somewhere, e.g., `df["result"] = df.apply....`

Comment: Hi cmosig, that did the trick. I got the output I wanted. Thanks for youur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the comment:

You need to set `axis=1` when you want to apply a function to rows. So `df.apply(lambda row: get_entities(row), axis=1)`. `axis` is set to 0 by default otherwise.